# Pulling columns from Active Directory Search window ("The Find User, Contacts and Groups" search window)

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to pull and list (I don't really care where, in a DataTable, textbox, etc) all the columns and properties name of the Active Directory Search window (column name like Name, First Name, Last Name, etc)

I think the DirectorySearcher assembly can achieve that but all the examples I find are examples with fields and properties already known.

Comment: I tried using ActiveDirectorySchema, DirectorySearcher, DirectoryEntry, SearchResultCollection, domain, and forest. Can't really find references to pull the columns from the window though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Directory is a Directory Service based on LDAP. To query a directory, you must know the property names. Here is a [pretty expansive list you can use](http://www.rlmueller.net/References/ADUCProperties.xls)

Comment: So even though the Columns are there when you do a search with the "Find User, Contacts and Groups" window there's no way to pull the column name and properties from that window?

Comment: are you just not sure what attributes you are looking for? you can browse ADSI Edit to see all of the attributes to decide which ones you want to pull.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
    string firstname = found.GivenName;
    string familyname = found.Surname;
    // and so on
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`